# Enforce type in VueJS3 route parameter

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

I would like to set up routing for my application so that a parameter can only be from a set of given values.

Somewhere in my code I have an array like:

```ts
const people = ['mary', 'bob', 'pat'] as const;
type tPersonId = typeof people[number];
```

My router currently looks like:

```ts
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  strict: true,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: HomeView,
    },
    {
      path: '/person/:id',
      name: 'person',
      component: () => import('@/views/PersonView.vue'),
    },
    {
      path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
      name: '404',
      component: NotFoundView,
    }
  ]
});
```

I want to enforce that the value for `:id` can only be one of the names from my `people` array and/or can be typed as a `tPersonId` (and therefore I don't need to add conditional logic in my PersonView component).  The result should be that `/person/bob` is a valid route, but `/person/jennifer` is not (and gets caught by the 404 route).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@nuggz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78014802/1327340) suggestion works ok, with a few changes:

1. I used a per-route guard instead of a global guard, which probably means the router is doing less work on each navigation as it'll only check the `/person/:id` routes.
2. TS complained about `people.includes(id)` when `people` is a constant array.  I couldn't find a good solution to this, so just reworked the code so that `people` is a keyed `Record<peopleId,...>` type, and then used `Object.keys(people).include(id)` for the check.

So my router now looks like this:

```js
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  strict: true,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: HomeView,
    },
    {
      path: '/person/:id',
      name: 'person',
      beforeEnter: (to, from) => {
        const id = to.params.id as string;
        if (!Object.keys(people).includes(id)) {
          return { name: '404'}
        }
      },
      component: () => import('@/views/PersonView.vue'),
    },
    {
      path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
      name: '404',
      component: NotFoundView,
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To restrict the `:id` parameter values to the names in your `people` array and redirect to a 404 page for any "non-allowed" value, you can use a global [route guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) with Vue Router.

Configure your router and add a global beforeEarch guard:

```js
const router = createRouter({
    routes: [
        // your routes
    ]
});

// Now the navigation guard
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if(to.path.startsWith('/person/')) {
        const id = to.params.id;
        if(people.includes(id)) {
            next(); // if the id is in the array, continue with the route
        } else {
            next('/404');
        }
    } else {
        next(); // For any other route
    }
});
```

> Every guard function receives two arguments:
>
> `to`: the target route location in a normalized format being navigated to.
>
> `from`: the current route location in a normalized format being navigated away from.

This code should check if the current route starts with `/person/` and whether the `id` is within your `people` array. If the `id` is valid, it allows the navigation to proceed.

Hope this helps you!